# Select id and timestamp from multiple MySQL tables with different schemas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a few different tables in MySQL with different schemas, but all of the tables have an auto-incremented ID and a timestamp (more accurately column name is "create_timestamp" of type datetime).

To give this question more context, I'm building a social data aggregator and my MySQL DB is just cached data from the social media APIs. So the tables are for Instagram, Youtube Videos, Tweets, etc. My goal is to query for 20 records total from a mix of each of these, based on their create_time. Since each media API returns different data, each table has a very different schema.

In pseudo code, I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
SELECT * FROM instagrams, tweets, youtube_videos, tumblr_posts ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT 20;
```

I realize I might have to just query for all ID's and table types, and then loop through these in PHP to get their individual data. For example, more pseudocode:

**MySQL**

```
SELECT id, table_name FROM instagrams, tweets, youtube_videos, tumblr_posts ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT 20;
```

**PHP**

```
-For each result from that query as $row, query for:
SELECT * FROM $row["table_name"] WHERE id=$row["id"]
```

What's the best and most efficient way to get this data into my PHP app?

---

**UPDATE**:

Thanks Dan, using UNION this is what I came up with to select the id, and table name.

```
SELECT id, create_timestamp, "instagrams" as "table_name" FROM instagrams
UNION
SELECT id, create_timestamp, "tumblr_posts" as "table_name" FROM tumblr_posts
UNION
SELECT id, create_timestamp, "wordpress_posts" as "table_name" FROM wordpress_posts
UNION
SELECT id, create_timestamp, "tweets" as "table_name" FROM tweets
UNION
SELECT id, create_timestamp, "youtube_videos" as "table_name" FROM youtube_videos
UNION
SELECT id, create_timestamp, "manual_photo" as "table_name" FROM manual_photo
ORDER BY create_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Then in PHP I'm looping through and query for their individual records one at a time.

Comment: I think a union query is your best bet to get the 20 most recent records.  Then get information from the results of this query.

Comment: Thanks! Never used UNION before but looks like it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to get latest 20 entries of each table, and use the outer query to get the latest 20 entries from the unioned set. And seen as you want the table name in PHP, just put the table name in the select clause.

You cannot just union select * of each table, because as you said, the tables have different 'schemes'.

```
select * from (
    (select 'instagram' as table, id, create_time from instagram order by create_time desc limit 20)
    union
    (select 'tweets' as table, id, create_time from tweets order by create_time desc limit 20)
    union
    (select 'youtube_videos' as table, id, create_time from youtube_videos order by create_time desc limit 20)
    union
    (select 'tumblr_posts' as table, id, create_time from tumblr_posts order by create_time desc limit 20)
)t
order by create_time
limit 20
```